# Installers created using install4j on linux are unable to launch the application in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, install4j

I have an install4j setup on Linux machine. When I install the application on windows, installation process completes but then the application is not launched.

I have checked installation.log and found that an action is not executed properly and so some variables are not assigned values.

I have the same setup on Windows machine that creates installers for all platforms fine. So there is nothing wrong with the setup I have.

Install4j version I am using is 6.1.5

Comment: This is most certainly not a general problem, the install4j installer itself is generated on Linux. Please share more detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because of the known bug in install4j version 6.1.5. Working fine for former and later versions.